# How to access properties that I have created dynamically?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

In the thinking of rebuilding Highlighted content properties, I have created button that add fields in the property pane but now I would like to know how to store the value of these fields and how to access these values.

I have created an array in wich one I push PropertyPaneDropdown when I click "AddButton". Each PropertyPaneDropDown have its own property because I use variable that I increment. My problem is that these property doesn't exist in the webartProps Interface.

```
private buttonAdd(tab, tabID): any {  
let nameID;
if(tab == this.dynamicTypes){
  nameID = "DT";
}
let ind = tab.length;
if(ind == 1){
  tab.push(PropertyPaneButton('deleteButton'+nameID+"0", {
    text: 'Delete',
    buttonType: PropertyPaneButtonType.Hero,
    icon: 'Delete',
    onClick: this.buttonDelete.bind(this,nameID+"0")
  }));
}
tab.push(PropertyPaneDropdown(nameID+(tabID++), {
  label: 'Type',
  options: [
    { key: 'Documents', text: 'Documents'},
    { key: 'Pages', text: 'Pages'},
    { key: 'News', text: 'News'},
    { key: 'Videos', text: 'Videos'},
    { key: 'Images', text: 'Images'},
    { key: 'Events', text: 'Events'},
    { key: 'Issues', text: 'Issues'},
    { key: 'Tasks', text: 'Tasks'},
    { key: 'Links', text: 'Links'},
    { key: 'Contacts', text: 'Contacts'},
    { key: 'All', text: 'All'}
  ],
  selectedKey: 'Documents'
}),
PropertyPaneButton('deleteButton'+nameID+(tabID-1), {
  text: 'Delete',
  buttonType: PropertyPaneButtonType.Hero,
  icon: 'Delete',
  onClick: this.buttonDelete.bind(this,nameID+(tabID-1), tab)
})
);
console.log(tab);
this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
```

}

```
protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {

let dynamicProps: any;


let source :any;

if(this.properties.typeOfContent){
  source = PropertyPaneDropdown('source', {
    label: 'Source',
    options: [
      { key: 'This site', text: 'This site'},
      { key: 'A document library on this site', text: 'A document library on this site'},
      { key: 'This site collection', text: 'This site collection'},
      { key: 'Select sites', text: 'Select sites'},
      { key: 'All sites', text: 'All sites'}
    ],
    selectedKey: 'This site'
  });

  let addTypeButton = PropertyPaneButton('addButton',{
    text: 'Add content type',
    buttonType: PropertyPaneButtonType.Hero,
    icon: 'Add',
    onClick: this.buttonAdd.bind(this, this.dynamicTypes, this.dynamicTypeID)
  });

  let addDocumentButton = PropertyPaneButton('addButton',{
    text: 'Add document type',
    buttonType: PropertyPaneButtonType.Hero,
    icon: 'Add',
    onClick: this.buttonAdd.bind(this, this.dynamicDocuments, this.dynamicDocumentID)
  })

  switch(this.properties.source){
    case "This site":
      dynamicProps = this.dynamicTypes.concat(addTypeButton);
      break;
    case "A document library on this site":
      dynamicProps = PropertyPaneDropdown('documentLibrary', {
        label: 'Document library',
        options: [
          { key: 'Documents', text: 'Documents'},
          { key: 'Documents Publics', text: 'Documents Publics'},
          { key: 'From Templates', text: 'From Templates'},
          { key: 'Reporting Templates', text: 'Reporting Templates'},
          { key: 'Search Config List', text: 'Search Config List'},
          { key: 'Site Assets', text: 'Site Assets'},
          { key: 'Site Collection Documents', text: 'Site Collection Documents'},
          { key: 'Style Library', text: 'Style Library'},
        ],
        selectedKey: 'Documents'
      });
      dynamicProps = dynamicProps.concat(this.dynamicDocuments).concat(addTypeButton);
      break;
    case "This site collection":
      dynamicProps = this.dynamicTypes.concat(addTypeButton);
      break;
    case "Select sites":
      dynamicProps = this.dynamicTypes.concat(addTypeButton);
      break;
    case "All sites":
      dynamicProps = this.dynamicTypes.concat(addTypeButton);
      break;
  }
}
else{
  source  = PropertyPaneLabel('emptyLabel', {
    text: ""
  });
  dynamicProps = []
}




return {
  pages: [
    {
      header: {
        description: "Parameters"
      },
      displayGroupsAsAccordion: true,
      groups: [
        {
          groupName: "Content",
          groupFields:[
            PropertyPaneToggle('typeOfContent', {
              label: 'Type of Content',
              onText: 'SharePoint Lists',
              offText: 'Raw Images'
            }),
            source
          ].concat(dynamicProps)
        },
        {
          groupName: "Filters",
          groupFields:[

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Here some of my code to show you how I though it.
I'm kind of stuck on that so it would be so helpfull to have some help.
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, every PropertyPane contructor takes as first parameter the variable it will use to store the data.

So your `this.properties` object should contain any of the variables you declared. I'm not sure if you actually said and tested this object ?

Comment: Hello, my problem is, as these variables are dynamically created, I can't access them via this.properties because they are not declared in the Props interface

Comment: If this is only a TypeScript issue, you can access any property doing `this.properties["my-dynamic-property"]` to at least test if the property is there

Comment: It's perfectly working with this syntax this.properties["my-dynamic-property"] Thank you very much really